# Why XFetchBuffer() returns null instead of clipboard?

Tags: x11, copy-paste

```
int N, atom;
atom = XInternAtom (display, "CLIPBOARD", false);
char *c = XFetchBuffer(display, &N, atom);
```

The code above supposed to get the string from the clipboard, but it only returns null. And `N` is `0` as well.

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize atom and display variables?

Comment: there was a typo, atom is declared int he first line here. but display is declared somewhere else and is valid because I use it for many other functions.

Answer (score 1):

`XFetchBuffer` works with cut buffers, not with the clipboard. Cut buffers are hardly ever used these days. Note the argument `XFetchBuffer` accepts is not an `Atom` but an integer. These are not the same thing.

If you need the clipboard, you need to follow [ICCCM](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.6) and write lots more code.